# Inserting a DataFrame into a database in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I need to iterate through a DataFrame using a for loop to insert preexisting data into a database. The data frame is called gelsdf and the database table is Gels. I cannot figure out how to make the VALUES portion of the insert clause work without receiving an error.

Here's my code:

```
count = 1

for i in range(len(gelsdf)): 
    curr = gelsdf.loc[count]
    %sql INSERT INTO Gels (GelID, Brand, GelCode, Size, GelName, GelLocation) VALUES (curr[0], curr[1], [curr[2], curr[3], curr[4], curr[5])
    count += 1
```

Comment: Why don't you use pandas `to_sql` method? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html Seems like that would be much easier.

Comment: +1 for `to_sql`.  If for some reason you can't use it, sharing the module you are using to create your sql connection will be helpful